Permission denied even if you enter the correct password when connecting to uuntu with ssh
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 version of ec2 and I got into trouble here.
Originally, public key access was good using a pem key on Ubuntu ec2, but I wanted to access ec2 only with a password without a pem key. So I changed some settings in the sshd_config file and now I can't log in any way.
I changed the setting to "Password Authentication yes"
Even when I connected to ssubuntu@ip-address, I kept getting the message Permission denied (publickey).
Since then, the setting of Pubkey Authentication no was added, resulting in a situation in which the public key could not be accessed.
Still, a window appears where you enter the password, but even if you enter the correct password, you cannot access ec2 with the message Permissio denied. try again.
Currently, I can't access Ubuntu ec2. (Even if I try to enter an instance with AWS, a message says Failed to connect to your instance. Error establishing SSH connection to your instance. Try again later.)
What should I do?

TO enable password based authentication you must make two things to yes in /etc/ssh/sshd_config file
PasswordAuthentication yes
KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
